# Why my list is not changing the way it's supposed to?

Tags: python, list, class, oop, matrix

I'm trying to build a method in my class `Circle` which gets a matrix (represented by a list of lists, each sublist represents a row) as an input.

The matrix has zero in every cell, and I'm supposed to place my circle in the center of the matrix and check if the `(i,j)` cell which represents the `(i,j)` point is contained in the circle, but for some reason I get a different output.

Here is an example:

```
mat = [[0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(7)] 
Circle(40, 10, 1).draw(mat)
```

The output I expect is:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But the output I get is:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Here's my code:

```
class Point():
    """ Holds data on a point (x,y) in the plane """

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        assert isinstance(x,(int, float)) and isinstance(y,(int, float)) 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Circle():
    """ Holds data on a circle in the plane """

    def __init__(self,*args):
        if len(args)==2:
            if isinstance(args[0],Point) and isinstance(args[1],(float,int)):
                assert args[1]>0
                self.center= args[0]
                self.radius= args[1]

        if len(args)==3:
            assert args[2]>0
            self.a=args[0]
            self.b=args[1]
            self.center= Point(self.a,self.b)
            self.radius= args[2]
    def contains(self,check): 

        if isinstance(check,(Point)):
            if math.sqrt((self.center.x-check.x)**2 + (self.center.y-check.y)**2) <= self.radius:
                return True
        if isinstance(check,Circle): 
            test= math.sqrt((self.center.x-check.center.x)**2 + (self.center.x-check.center.x)**2)
            if test < (abs((self.radius)-(check.radius))):
                return True

        else:
            return False

    def draw(self,mat):
        n=len(mat)
        m=len(mat[0])

        newcircle=Circle((int(m/2)+1),(int(n/2)+1),self.radius)
        for i,lst in enumerate(mat):
            for j,val in enumerate(lst):
                if  newcircle.contains(Point(i,j)):


                    mat[i][j]=1
```

Comment: That output looks exactly like your description - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I run the code I get a different output

Answer (score 1):

You're not placing your circle in the middle of the matrix.

```
newcircle=Circle((int(m/2)+1),(int(n/2)+1),self.radius)
```

should be

```
newcircle=Circle((int(n/2)),(int(m/2)),self.radius)
```

or possibly, since there is no need to use just integers here.

```
newcircle=Circle((n-1)/2.0,(m-1)/2.0,self.radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw a circle, you create a new circle in the center of the matrix, you check the cells that are inside and then you turn the value to 1 for those inside.

### 1) First, there is a problem with the function `contains` :

```
def contains(...):
    if (cond1):
        if (cond11)
            return True
    if (cond2):
        if (cond21)
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

If cond2 is true and cond21 is false, you will get a None.
To be more Pythonic, try:

```
def contains(...):
    if (cond1) and (cond11):
        return True
    elif (cond2) and (cond21):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You are sure in this case to have a True or a False.

### 2) Copy / Paste mistake

There is a copy / paste mistake in the function contains when instance is Circle.
You have forgotten to turn `y` into `x`.

### 3) Function `draw`

All you need for this function is the radius.
Be careful with the use of integers and floats; we have:

```
(int(5 / 2)) == (5 / 2) != (5 / 2.)
```

To be sure to have a float, write the divisor as a float `2.` instead of `2`

Your circle is created on a matrix which rows and columns indices start with 1 if you define the center using `int(len(mat) / 2.) + 1`.
Don't forget that `enumerate` indices starts at 0, not 1.
So, `int((len(mat) - 1) / 2.) + 1` (which is the same as `len(mat) / 2`) would be more accurate.

Seriously, Taha!